# Self Hosted OWIN WebAPI application won't bind to port when run as a Windows service

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, owin

I have a self hosted OWIN WebAPI application that is currently run from a non-elevated command prompt (running as local administrator) and works fine, accepting connections from the local machine and other machines on the network.

The app start code is:

```
using (WebApp.Start<Startup>(url: "http://+:9000/"))
{
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

and I have run the following to make sure the app can bind correctly:

```
netsh http add urlacl url=http://+:9000/ user=administrator
```

Now I'm trying to make it run as a Windows service. I've derived my main class from ServiceBase and moved the `WebApp.Start` into the `OnStart()` method. I run the service as the local administrator. The service starts and stays running, with debug logging showing me that it has gone as far as getting to the `WebApp.Start` line, but the app is not listening on port 9000 on any interfaces.

What have I messed up?

Comment: Are you sure the Windows Service is running under the account that was setup to bind to the port?

Comment: What account is used by service to log on? Have you assigned appropriate permissions for that account and port?

Comment: The service is set to log on as .\administrator, which is the user that was given permission with the netsh command above.

Comment: Have you tried restarting Windows and run the service again? 
On slightly unrelated note, you can try to use http://topshelf-project.com/ to simplify development of Windows Service. I have a couple of self-hosted OWIN Web API run as Windows Service using Topshelf. It seems to work quite well.